# Orthographe des termes médicaux composés

Tags: orthographe, préfixes, santé-et-médecine, mots-composés

Comment orthographier correctement les termes composés comme *supra-spinal*, *hyper-prolactinémie*, *anti-dépresseur*, *gastro-intestinal*, *cardio-vasculaire*, *intra-musculaire*, *péri-médullaire*, *immuno-allergique*, etc. ? Faut-il laisser le tiret ou peut-on les accoler ? Peut-être que les deux orthographes sont justes ?

Cela fait des années que mes professeurs utilisent indistinctement et me semble-t-il aléatoirement ces deux orthographes et j'aimerais être enfin sûre d'avoir des termes correctement orthographiés et de ne plus faire de phonétique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de règle générale, ce qui explique que chacun choisit d'utiliser ou non un trait d'union. La seule règle qu'il faille vraiment respecter est d'être cohérent sur l'orthographe d'un mot donné au sein d'un même texte.

En général, on a plus tendance à souder les deux éléments lorsque le premier est un préfixe courant comme *anti-* ou *intra-* et moins lorsqu'il s'agit d'un terme plus technique et plus rare comme *gastro-* et *immuno-*. Mais ce n'est pas une règle absolue. On a également d'autant plus tendance à omettre le trait d'union que le mot est d'usage courant.

Il y a un cas où le trait d'union s'impose : celui où la mise en commun des deux termes résulterait en un mot de prononciation différente. Par exemple, on ne peut pas retirer le trait d'union de *gastro-intestinal*. Suivant les règles d'orthographe traditionnelle, on pourrait marquer la diérèse par un tréma (*<s>*gastroïntestinal*</s>), mais cette construction n'est plus productive aujourd'hui.

Dans le cas particulier d'*anti-*, qui est très productif, on parvient à distinguer certaines tendances : dans le sens « remède contre » utilisé en médecine, le trait d'union est rare (donc *antidépresseur*), tandis que dans le sens d'opposition à une idée, le trait d'union est minoritaire lorsque le second terme exprime clairement une tendance de pensée (*anticommuniste*, *anticléricalisme*, aussi *anticlérical*), mais majoritaire lorsque le second terme est plus général (*anti-catholique*, *anti-classique*). (Source: [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/anti-))

Answer (score 2):

Le mieux est de consulter un dictionnaire.

Je trouve, par exemple :

[gastro-intestinal](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/gastro-intestinal)

[intramusculaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/intramusculaire)

[antidépresseur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/antid%C3%A9presseur)